# Multiple value parameter not loading on server

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, multiple-value

My problem is with the reporting services for sql2008:
-I add a parameter to **an already established report**, where I get the names of certain people. RespStep, and it shows on the preview. But when I upload it to the server, it wontshow: 
**It pretends it´s loading for less than a second and then the report stays in blank.**

NOTES:
This behavior happends only when I set the parameter to allow multiple value.

 I thought it was a null problem, but the column from where the parameter values come has no nulls and still presents these problems.

 I am desperate to know where the problem might be, on the server the data source and everything is well directed. Actually it shows no erros, just wont load anything and keep the page in blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just delete the report on server and re-depoly it.after that you can see the parameter in report

Comment: I´ve tryed. The thing is it wont load the report, I have changed the dataset on the server, I have redeployed the parameter. I am starting to believe it is related to the datatype, since when a select a subset of values it will work.

Comment: Actually I am convinced it is related to the data contained in that column or it´s treatment. <br> When I select a subset of values in the blank report it will work. But the problem is not a specific value (meaning that there is no value that wont display in a subset) <br> And then I have no idea where else to look for